# проблемы с window.addEventListener('resize',function()

Tags: javascript, html

В общем, когда использую window.addEventListener('resize',function() он вроде как работает, но нет. при изменении разрешения полностью исчезает все с сайта. не знаю как объяснить, лучше смотреть скриншоты.

```
function styles(){
        if(document.documentElement.clientWidth>900){
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">');
        }
        else{
            document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-mob.css" type="text/css">');     
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('resize',styles());
```

в коде подключаю разные стили для разных устройств, пока только разбираюсь как это работает.

вот так выглядит сайт до изменения масштаба.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а вот так после.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видно подключаются стили, но после них ничего нет.

Comment: document.write это что-то доисторическое. Не надо так делать

Comment: Для адаптации под размер экрана уже давно есть медиа-выражения и js для этого не нужен

Comment: это я знаю, но из того что я делал это работало только после перезагрузки. а как сделать так, чтобы автоматически подключались нужные стили при изменении масштаба?

Comment: Вы функцию неверно передаёте в слушатель

Comment: https://doka.guide/html/link/#uslovnaya-zagruzka-resursov-s-mediavyrazheniyami

Comment: У вас всё пропадает потому что `document.write` вызванный после загрузки документа всё стирает и начинает с чистого листа. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/write